# How to trigger an error: "You are not allowed to edit this post."

Tags: user-roles

How can I trigger error "You are not allowed to edit this post." when someone tries to edit the post?

Answer (score 1):

Check or Alter user `capabilities` on call of `current_user_can`. Check `current_user_can` fucntion and `has_cap` fitler for further info.